# Upload to Google Cloud storage from App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth, google-authentication

I've been bashing my head at this for over a day, but I can't figure out how to upload data to Google Cloud Storage via an app script attached to a google sheet. I've been running into issues with authorisation. I've copied the `getService` method from [here](https://www.labnol.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage) (pasted below) but the service keeps failing to receive authorisation. `service.hasAccess()` always returns false.

```
function uploadFileToGCS(dataJSON) {

  var service = getService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    Browser.msgBox("Failed to grant service access")
    return;
  }

  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET/o?uploadType=media&name=FILE'
    .replace("BUCKET", params.BUCKET_NAME)
    .replace("FILE", encodeURIComponent(params.FILE_PATH));

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    payload: dataJSON,
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    }
  });

  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}

function getService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('ctrlq')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setClientId(params.CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(params.CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force')
    .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Connected to Google Cloud Storage');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Access Denied');
  }
}
```

I've created OAUTH credentials for a web-app on the Google Cloud Console. I've also enabled the  Cloud Storage API and Google Cloud Storage JSON API. I'm unsure however on the redirect URL. (Ideally, I'd like to use a service account because I just want to take the values from the spreadsheet and upload them as a JSON file.)

Anyway, appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you bound this to a GCP project from the `Resources > Cloud Platform Project` menu item?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I believe the storage resource and the API creds are bound to the same project

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I have similar problems.  There is a direction to create the key with 'redirect URL containing your Google Apps Script project key', which perhaps needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think google app script project and google cloud project should be linked. You need to create a google cloud project to use this API.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when I wanted to duplicate an object in Cloud Storage. Not sure if this is the solution for you, but I'm putting it here in case someone need it.

Just use the XML-formmatted REST API with OAuth2 token, and the code looks like this:

```js
var objectSource = "SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME/SOURCE_OBJECT_NAME";
var url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME/NAME_OF_COPY";
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer '+ OAUTH2_TOKEN,
    "x-goog-copy-source": objectSource,
  },
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  });
```

Check out the Cloud Storage's document for differences between [copy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#copy) and [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same guide to upload Google Drive file to GCS and the function trigger point is at Google Sheet.

The code works for me once I have added these oauth scopes to the appscript.json manifest file

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"],
```

Comment: Not sure if bounding to the GCP project helps or not but I have done that too